# parse key-value in c

Tags: c, parsing

How do i parse key-value string in C and assign it to appropriate variable?

I.e. we will pass this string to a program:

```
x = 193
```

and it will assign value to appr. variable, so

```
printf("%i", x);
```

produces

```
193
```

Comment: Why? What is your _wider_ goal?

Comment: apart from sscanf pointed out in one of the answers, you may also look at strstr() function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given

```
char keyname[32];
int val;
```

where we want to store the name of the keyname and value of the integer assignment, and a string of the example format `const char * str = "x = 193"` we could use `sscanf()` C library function to do the parsing for us:

```
sscanf(str, "%32[^=]=%d", keyname, &val)
```

Note that for example `str = " x = 193"` will be store string `" x "` to  `keyname` so you still need to get rid of the extra spaces if you want flexible syntax with regards to spaces around the assignment and before the variable name.

The `sscanf()` will return the number of successful conversions, so you should test that it returns `2` in our case.

Once you got the variable name and its integer value stored in `keyname` and `val`, you can do like @unwind above suggest to see which variable you should assign `val` to, testing with `strcmp`. If you have a lot of fixed name variables, you could have a table and use a look-up function to make this prettier than one heck of an unmaintainable and error-prone long list of `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't magically introduce variables at run-time. When a C program is running, the names of the variables are long gone, the compiler needs that information to build the code but the CPU doesn't need it to run the code.

You're going to have to `strcmp()` against the known variable names, and assign accordingly. To optimize this (for many names values), you can of course use something like a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to store pairs of names and integers holding values.

Comment: While what you're saying is accurate, there are certainly ways to parse the OP's example input and store it as the value 193 assigned to the key "x". S/He wouldn't be able to then printf it exactly as shown of course, but the problem's solution doesn't have to be bound to only existing known variable names.

Comment: @ValeriyAntonov using only c, you're at a little bit of a disadvantage. C++, for example, makes it easier using a `map` container and other systems call the same thing a dictionary. Using c, you need to implement the map / dictionary yourself, or find a good implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970656/c-dictionary-map appears to show a solution for this for c, though I have not personally tried that solution. If it's too complicated, a simple map could be made easily with a struct of {char *name, int value, struct * next} to hold your entries (and supporting code, of course).

Comment: @ValeriyAntonov, you can take a look at [my map implementation](https://github.com/ShabbyX/shDS) (along with other structures). All you need is simple copy/compare callbacks and the data structures there would work with any kind of data (primitives, complex objects or pointers).